# Disable azure function app remote debugging using Az Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell

Does anyone know how i can disable remote debugging using Az Powershell? 
I know we can do that using az cli, which looks something like this

az functionapp config set \
  --name Appname \
  --ftps-state "Disabled" \
  --subscription mysubscription \
  --remote-debugging-enabled false \
  --resource-group myresourcegroup

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer Joy. :)

Comment: How do you know there is a properties under $Resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the command below, it works fine on my side.

```
$Resource = Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName <Resource Group Name> -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName "<Function App Name>" -ApiVersion "2018-02-01"
$Resource.Properties.remoteDebuggingEnabled = "False"
$Resource | Set-AzResource -ApiVersion "2018-02-01" -Force
```

[image]